# Can't find out what's the with my sed regex implementing a variable into it

Tags: regex, bash, sed

While trying to include a variable in a sed oneliner I ran into syntax error every time while I've seen such regexes elsewhere. Can somebody help me please?
Code:

```
echo `tr " " "\n"< $1| sed 's/'"$i"'//g' | tr "\n" " "` >> alt.txt
```

($i stands for boy as an input example)

Input:

```
one boy two three tree also boy boy boy
```

Output:

```
one two three tree also
```

Comment: Also, if i use : " mv alt.txt $1" the initial file given as the $1 parameter becomes empty...

Comment: `sed 's/'"$i"'//g'` -> `sed "s/$i//g"`

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin . This solved the pattern. However, may I ask why sometimes they alter the regex? Since I saw this form of it too and then saw the one implemented by myself...

Comment: I suspect it would depend on the context of the regex, and what the previous quoting had been. While `sed 's/'"$i"'//g'` is equivalent to `sed 's/'  "$i"  '//g'`, `sed` may complain about getting pieces of any expression instead of an entire expression.

Comment: `'s/'"$i"'//g'` and `"s/$i//g"` are equivalent, `'s/' "$i" '//g'` is different.

Comment: no need to use sed to do this type of replacement variable expansion is more efficient : `echo "${var//$i}"`, where `var='one boy two three tree also boy boy boy'` and  `i=boy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I consider your requirement as per your input and out put I can provide you the below solution:-

```
i="boy"
echo 'one boy two three tree also boy boy boy' | sed "s/$i //g" | sed "s/$i//g"
```

In a `sed` command when you use variable you need double quote `""`. Also you don't need the space after `boy` hence there is a space after variable `$i` in the above command. But last `boy` is not followed by any space and to remove that boy the last option `s/$i//g`. Now your output will be:-

```
one two three tree also
```